# Strange redirection to a different website on my chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, browser, redirection

I have been using a certain website (AirTable.com) on a regular basis.  Yesterday I noticed that my chrome browser refused to go to the website (error was certificate not valid).  Upon inspection, I found that it is because, for some reasons, my browser has been redirected to a different website (web.remscripts.com) and it is this different website that has an invalid an invalid certificate.

I tried a different browser (Firefox) and I did not have the same problem there.

Do you know what happened? Is the website (or my computer) infected?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen in Incognito mode ?

Comment: No. This was the normal mode of Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: When the incident happened, I was not using Chrome Incognito Mode but the normal mode.

Comment: You need to try it again in both modes and report back.

Comment: Thanks!  I just tried.  The problem did not happen with the normal mode but with the Incognito mode.  This time the web browser was redirection to a different website (which, strangely, is an EDU site)

Issue to:

Common Name (CN) *.tams.nursing.duke.edu
Organization (O) <Not Part Of Certificate>
Organizational Unit (OU) <Not Part Of Certificate>

Issued by:

Common Name (CN) Amazon RSA 2048 M02
Organization (O) Amazon
Organizational Unit (OU) <Not Part Of Certificate>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149144/discussion-between-leeyuiwah-and-harrymc).